# Defining class field and calling parent's constructor

Tags: java, static, extends, super

These are two classes of code that I wrote.. the problem here is I am not sure how to define class fields to represent Grass, fire and water as a Type using static..
Also I am not sure if I had used the super function the right way.. How do I properly call the parent's constructor so that I dont have to re define "knockedOut boolean" and be able to use Fire as the type?
Question could be confusing but I am not sure how to explain it better :( sorry

```
public abstract class Pokemon {
private String name;
private String type;
private int attack;
private int health;
private boolean knockedOut;
static private String Grass;
static private String Water;
static private String Fire;  
public Pokemon (String n, String t, int a, int h) {
    name = n;//state
    type = t;//state
    attack = a;//state
    health = h;//state
    knockedOut = false;
}

public abstract int takeDamage(Pokemon enemy);

public String toString() {
    return  "}";
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public int getAttack() {
    return attack;
}

public void setAttack(int attack) {
    this.attack = attack;
}

public int getHealth() {
    return health;
}

public void setHealth(int health) {
    this.health = health;
}

public boolean isKnockedOut() {
    return knockedOut;
}

public void setKnockedOut(boolean knockedOut) {
    this.knockedOut = knockedOut;
}


}

public abstract class Charizard extends Pokemon {
private static String Fire;
private int attackFire;
private int healthFire;
private static String Water;
private static String Grass;
public Charizard(int a, int h) {
    super("Charizard", Fire, a, h);
    attackFire = a;
    healthFire = h;


}
public int takeDamage(Pokemon enemy){
    int enemyAttack = enemy.getAttack();
    if(enemy.getType().equals(Water)){
        enemy.setHealth(enemy.getHealth()-attackFire/2);
        healthFire = healthFire-enemy.getAttack()*2;
        if(enemy.getHealth()<=0){
            enemy.setKnockedOut(true);
        }
    }
    else if(enemy.getType().equals(Fire)){
        enemy.setHealth(enemy.getHealth()-attackFire/2);
        healthFire = healthFire-enemy.getAttack()*2;
        if(enemy.getHealth()<=0){
            enemy.setKnockedOut(true);
        }
    }
    else if(enemy.getType().equals(Grass)){
        enemy.setHealth(enemy.getHealth()-attackFire/2);
        healthFire = healthFire-enemy.getAttack()/2;
        if(enemy.getHealth()<=0){
            enemy.setKnockedOut(true);
        }
        if(healthFire <=0){
            Charizard.set = true;
        }
    }
    return enemyAttack;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You want to declare your different types like this:

```
static public final String GRASS= "Grass";
static public final String WATER = "Water";
static public final String FIRE = "Fire";
```

(I'm following the established convention here that fields declared `static`, `public`, and `final` should have names in all uppercase letters.)

By declaring these fields `public`, any other classes (including those that extend `Pokemon`, such as `Charizard`) that might need to test the type of a `Pokemon` can use them.  By declaring them `final`, nobody can change them even though they are `public`.  By giving them initial values, you make them actually useful for distinguishing different types of `Pokemon`, as well as avoid the inevitable `NullPointerException` that would happen the first time you executed something like `p.getType().equals(Pokemon.FIRE)`

As for `knockedOut`, it looks like you're handling it the right way.  The field `knockedOut` is private in `Pokemon` but you've provided public getter and setter methods that other classes can (and do) use to access it.